# Get 10 random rows that change weekly (featured entries)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

I try to get 10 random rows of a table. Many similar questions are out there but I have got an additional condition: I want this list to update weekly, 52 times a year. These 10 items are going to be the **"random featured ones of this week."**

So, I found this snippet of getting random rows that change each time you invoke the script

```
select top 10 percent * from [yourtable] order by newid();
```

The problem with  it is that I can't simply add a seed, which in this case would be the `week-of-year`. Any idea how to implement this?

Comment: Why not run the randomisation once a week and store the result in another table?

Comment: I'm confused by what you're after, if it's 10 random each week, how does re-running this query not work? Also, if you really just want top 10, remove 'percent' from your select.

Comment: Why do you have mysql and phpmyadmin tags when you present TSQL code? What RDBS are you actually using SQL Server or MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code sample is T-SQL (SQL Server).  So, to do this in SQL Server is pretty easy:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by datepart(wk, thedate) order by newid()) as seqnum
      from [yourtable] t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 10;
```

MySQL does not support `row_number()`, so the approach would be different in that database.

Comment: @poitroae . . . `wk` is an argument to the `datepart` function saying "get me the week of the year (strictly speaking, the year should be included as well).  The documentation is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(v=sql.105).aspx. The `thedate` argument is whatever date column you are using to define the week.

Comment: @poitroae . . . The solution is quite different in MySQL.  There is no similarity at all in the approaches in the two databases.

Comment: That's what I got so far, yet I am a bit confused with the entire syntax. http://ideone.com/4U637b